# How to create two rabbitmq connection for producers and consumers wehen use rabbitmq transport in Masstransit

Tags: .net, masstransit

How to create two rabbitmq connection for producers and consumers when use rabbitmq transport in Masstransit.
Separate the connections for publishers and consumers to achieve high throughput. RabbitMQ can apply back pressure on the TCP connection when the publisher is sending too many messages for the server to handle. If you consume on the same TCP connection, the server might not receive the message acknowledgments from the client, thus effecting the consume performance. With a lower consume speed, the server will be overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have high message rate scenarios that are actually triggering RabbitMQ to apply back pressure via TCP, I'd suggest producing the initial messages from a separate bus instance (possibly also in two separate services) (meaning messages produced outside of a consumer, such as `bus.Publish` or via a send endpoint.

In my performance testing, I have yet to see any issues related to heavy loads on a single connection – even on smaller RabbitMQ instances.